# How to allow access to a folder in AWS s3 and deny access to all other folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to allow access to a folder with certain file extension. I have this policy created:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1464968545158",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "allow-policy-1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123123:user/myuser-s3-uploader"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/only-allowed-folder/*/*.jpg",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/only-allowed-folder/*/*.jpeg",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/only-allowed-folder/*/*.png"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "allow-policy-2",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

With this policy, I get access denied always. If I remove the second one, however, `allow-policy-2`, it works.

I also replaced `"Principal" : "*"` with `"arn:aws:iam::123123:user/myuser-s3-uploader"` but get the same behaviour.

Is this because `Deny` has precedence over `Allow`? Is there a way to achieve this?

FYI, I am using AWS SDK to generate a presigned URL with the same user and then my front-end is using that presigned URL to upload/PUT files. I couldn't find a way to handle this via presigned URL.

Comment: Your Deny takes priority, making your Allow pointless. Why do you even need Deny? By default objects are private, so unless you have incorrectly designed the access in the first place, you shouldn't need Deny here.

Comment: I removed "Deny" but then you can upload files anywhere. Does that mean the user has more permissions itself?

Comment: Yes. Some other policies grant the permissions. Maybe user belong to some group with such permissions?

Comment: Thanks @Marcin The user had permission at user level that was overriding the bucket policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove deny policy (that you named "allow-policy-2"). On default there is no access granted to any object so I don't see the point of adding deny policy and it looks like it overrides allow policy that you have created as first in the statement ("allow-policy-1")

Comment: Thanks... When I remove it, then they can upload and even create new folder. So if that's the case I think the user I am using has admin access to the whole aws. I need to look into it.